How to get back deleted files in git
Branch A has files x.js and y.js. Create branch B from A so that B also has x.js and y.js. Go back to branch A, delete y.js then add z.js and edit x.js, each change is committed. Finally, how can branch A have file y.js (i.e. A has x.js, y.js, z.js).
I tried to get y from B by merging, but it didn't work.
Here's what I think:


From your branch A
# the "legacy" way
git checkout B -- y.js

# the modern way
git restore --source=B y.js

then just add and commit.

beat me to it! :P

Once in a while ;-)

It worked, but if i delete a lot of files do i have to do this multiple times?

You can also list multiple paths after -- (separated with spaces), and use wildcards in paths, like somedir/* or *.js

As an alternative to @Romain's answer, you might want to consider reasoning in terms of commits rather than single files. Especially, if you have to check out several files, and their set of changes represents one or more commits.
If you would like to reflect into branch B one or more changes introduced in branch A, you can use git cherry-pick.
# making sure to be on branch B
git checkout B

# picking commits from branch A
git cherry-pick <commit1>, ..., <commitN>

Instead, if you would like to include the whole set of changes from another branch, but you're not ready to merge yet, you could consider rebasing B on top of A. This would include in B all the commits in A that weren't present in B after their divergence, moving B's base to A's head commit.
# making sure to be on branch B
git checkout B

# rebase B on top of branch A
git rebase A

